# How do you use gettext on server (Apache) you can’t restart?

Tags: php, apache, gettext, shared-hosting, php-gettext

[I asked this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/104224/how-do-you-use-gettext-on-server-apache-you-cant-restart) but I didn't get any response. I try here...

I developped a site on my web server at home.

When I modify the translation files, I have to restart the web server Apache.

```
/etc/init.d/httpd graceful
```

Easy...

Suppose that my site is hosted on shared host.

Suppose now I need to modify the translation files.

**I can't restart the server...**

How do you use `gettext` in this context?

Are you allow to *restart* the server with the option graceful only?

Does the share host restart the server once a day to resolve this kind of problem?

How do you work with such constraints?

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/13629035/245428, no need to reboot apache nor change domain.

Comment: Could you please edit the selected answer with which advice helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the post here on the gettext function has some information for making gettext work without restarting apache:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php#58310

Answer (score 6):

call `clearstatcache();`

after making translation from `*.po` to `*.mo`

Answer (score 2):

You can rename your *.mo file and your gettext domain to flush gettext cache without restarting apache server.But in production environment,it's unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other solution than to **brutally force** a cache miss for each and every *.mo file every time one of them changes. Change a single string? New cache era!

I do this by writing middleware that copies all *.mo files to a timestamp-named directory (the timestamp being that of the newest *.mo file) and updates the application config with the new message path - if the newest timestamp actually changed, that is. Thus textdomains are now loaded from completely different paths, and **this** is what finally manages to kill the stupid gettext cache **stinking dead**.