# Translation files PO/MO cached by Apache

Tags: translation, php-7, gettext

I'm using PO/MO files for gettext PHP 7 extensions.
I found that many times I update the PO/MO files but the web page transations is not updates and I have to restart Apache!

Is there any way to avoid Apache restart and force file reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625659/how-to-clear-phps-gettext-cache-without-restart-apache-nor-change-domain#answer-13629035) for this problem of cache when using `gettext` for i18n internationalization.

The solution linked above will flush the cache after every requests, but as @xiaoyi said, this solution is not something you should use in `production` environment.

As far as I am concerned, I already used gettext but I didn't remember any problem of apache caching. I was using `POEdit` for editing & compile PO/MO files.

**EDIT :** I guess that using `php-fpm` causes this problem because I wasn't using `php-fpm` and wasn't concerned about this issue.

Good luck

Comment: For apache caching I meant gettext module caching